# drop character from first or the last

Tags: replace, concatenation, case

i have three fields in my table:
A,B and C
i want to concatenate some expressions with the comma character  regarding if the field is positif or not, here is my sql request:

```
 select 
 ' ' || (case when A >0 Then 'A is positif' End) || ','
 || (case when B >0 Then 'B is positif' End) || ','
 || (case when C >0 Then 'C is positif' End) || ',' AS result
From table;
```

the problem is when i have just one positif value then i got the comma in then end, however it should just separate values and **not appear in the end or in the beginning**, can any one help please to delete the comma from then end or give an alternative for the whole treatment?
thank you in advance.

Regards;

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with substring function.

```
 select 
 substring((case when A >0 Then ',A is positif' End) 
 || (case when B >0 Then ',B is positif' End) 
 || (case when C >0 Then ',C is positif' End),2)  AS result
From table;
```